# Can I find out where a Python application crashed using the data dump?

Tags: python, debugging

My application crashed recently on a client's computer. I suspect it's because of PyQt's own memory management, which can lead to a invalid memory accesses when not properly handled.

When Python crashes like this, no backtrace is printed, only a data dump is written to the disk.

Is there a possibility to find out where in the Python code the crash occured?

Here's the dump: http://pastie.org/768550

Answer (score 8):

Is this a linux core dump?  If so you can examine it with gdb.  You will need to run in on a system with an identical OS and version of Python, including 3rd party libraries.  Run `gdb -c /path/to/core/file`.  Once gdb has loaded then the command `bt` will list the stack trace for the main thread, and `thread apply all bt` will list the stack trace for all threads.

How useful this will be depends on whether the version of Python includes the full symbol table (i.e. is a debug build of Python) - if it is not, then you will only see addresses as offsets to the main C entry points.  However this can still be of some use in diagnosing what went wrong.

If it is some other OS that does not support gdb then you are on your own - presumably the OS will have its own debugging tools.

**Edit:**

There is a page on the Python wiki describing [how to get a python stack trace with gdb](https://wiki.python.org/moin/DebuggingWithGdb).

However a quick look at the link in the question shows that the OS is Windows, so gdb is of no use.  The information in the Windows dump is minimal, so I think you are out of luck.

My only suggestions are:

1. try to reproduce the crash in-house.
2. get the user to reproduce the bug while running a tool that will catch the crash and do a proper memory dump.  It is about a decade since I have done serious windows debugging so I don't know what tools are available now - there used to be one called Dr.Watson, but it may be obsolete.

If the user can't reproduce the crash then you are out of luck, on the other hand if it never happens again it is not really that big a problem. ;-)

**Update:**

Google tells me that Dr Watson is still the default crash handler on Windows XP (and presumably other versions of Windows) - the stack dump that was linked in the question probably came from it.  However the default data saved by Dr Watson is fairly minimal, but you can configure it to save more - see [this article](https://web.archive.org/web/20080521052413/http://www.ibphoenix.com:80/main.nfs?a=ibphoenix&page=ibp_pdb_win32).  In short, if you run `drwtsn32 -i` it will pop up a dialog to let you set the options.

Comment: nope, not linux for sure (look at the process list in the dump :P)

Comment: I'd be really interested in a _Python_ backtrace, which I cannot get using gdb I think. (Symbolizing the dump should be possible I think.)

Comment: I already tried reproducing it on the user's machine, didn't work. I mean there's a change of 0.0000001% that the user's memory is corrupt or Windows screwed up.

Comment: I know nothing about Dr.Watson, but from the process list it looks like it might have been running?

Comment: The computer is configured to store the minimal data dump (64kb), I guess I shouldn't mess with those settings. Additionally, I don't think that I've got a big chance to get anything useful from that minimal stack. I guess I'll just wait for it to happen again and then try to reproduce it.

Answer (score 3):

There's a file named `gdbinit` in the Python source tree (in `Misc/gdbinit`) which provides a set of macros for gdb so as to display the current interpreter context. Just type `source gdbinit` in gdb and then you can execute macros such as `pystack`. The list of available macros can be obtained simply by reading the file's source code.
(you can find it directly here: http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Misc/gdbinit?view=log).

Of course, if the crash is so severe that it has corrupted the interpreter's internal structures, the macros may fail or crash. Also, it is better to compile the interpreter in debug mode, otherwise gdb may fail to locate the required symbols and variables.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it helps, but if you can catch the exception, you could use http://github.com/gooli/pydump to store a dump and load it later in a Python debugger.

Comment: Link-only answer. Answers should contain the relevant code. If the link is removed, this is just a comment. The question should be closed to "Needs details or clarity" because the Pastebin reference is dead.

Answer (score 0):

Does your application produce a log?  If so, you can have logging produce an in-memory log which you might be able to find within the core dump.  Also, you can have them send you the log file itself *instead* of the core dump.

Answer (score 0):

You did not mention Python version you use. Since Python 3.3 you can use `faulthandler` which prints a traceback whenever a core dump occurs. You could set the environment variable

```
$ export PYTHONFAULTHANDLER=1
```

or enable it in the code manually:

```
import faulthandler
faulthandler.enable()
```

There is already a question about potential downsides of `faulthandler` here [python: Is there a downside to using faulthandler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21733856/python-is-there-a-downside-to-using-faulthandler)